# C# XNA - Abilities / Spells

Tags: c#, enums, xna

i've been figuring a little about abilities... like in DOTA, LoL and other MOBA / MMORPG games.  If i would make a game with character selection in the beginning, and in-game it would have spells / abilities and such..

What would a correct way of doing this be? Should i make one Champion class, with all values and textures, or initialize it in Game1.cs like `Champion champ = new Champion(texture, name, Q-ability name, Q-cooldown, Q-damage, Q-manacost)` - but that would take TONS of diffrent declarations...

Should i make a Champion folder and make a seperate class of them all? And also the abilities - i'm thinking about maaking an **enum** to keep them, or would a List or another variable work better? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at these: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns

Comment: The composite strategy pattern would fit this problem quite well http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119877/Patterns-In-Practice-Strategy-and-Composite

Answer (score 3):

For such a game, I'd recommend the use of an entity system (http://entity-systems.wikidot.com/). These allow you to create separate spell, ability, player, character etc classes and to compose them into highly configurable entities. I ported the popular Ash entity framework to C#, which is available at https://github.com/DavidArno/Ash.NET, which may be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Beside of an entity system which David Arno suggested, if I wanted to do this, I'd go with a single `Hero` class and then with a list of abilities inside it. Abilities are all the same, different thing is their factors. For instance, how much damage an ability can deliver and etc. This way you have to instantiate all of your champions and their abilities.

Comment: combining and merging properties. like shooting arrow, bullet, or fire ball is more/less same, both have velocity, direction, damage, distance... only animation/textures are different. and then you could have some simple enum that will say what kind of weapon is so you will know how to handle them. sounds easy, but project will grow like crazy very soon.

Comment: Well this is the data phase that you have to feed it to your system and I think there is no detour on it. And I assure you, entity system won't do any magic. It's just a wrapper to hold parts together, you still have to declare all of the distinct properties.